# Cannot set value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the value of a control in Javascript and yet nothing I am doing works?

```
<input id="SiteID2" value="1"/>
```

I have tried loads of different ways like

```
$("#SiteID2").value  = 3;
$("#SiteID2").val  = 3;
```

Nothing seems to work?

Maybe I am doing something really obviously wrong?

Can someone help please?

Paul

Comment: `$("#SiteID2").val(3)`. Notice this is using jQuery. `val` is a function that needs to be passed an argument to set the value. If the value is omitted, it reads the input instead and returns the current value.

Comment: if you're using jquery you have to do it like `$("#SiteID2").val(3)` not `$("#SiteID2").val  = 3`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered within the documentation's first paragraph. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jquery `val(value)` function to set the `value`.

```js
//sets the value of SiteID2 with 3
$('#SiteID2').val('3');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="SiteID2" value="1"/>
```

Or if you are using pure javascript then you can assign value by `getElementById`.

```js
document.getElementById('SiteID2').value = '3';
```

```html
<input id="SiteID2" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Javascript, you could use

```
document.getElementById("#SiteID2").value = 3
```

Using jQuery things are slightly different:

```
$("#SiteID2").val(3).
```

In jQuery, `val` is a function of the jQuery DOM object (which is a wrapper around the native DOM element) that needs to be passed an argument to set the value. If the value is omitted, it reads the input instead and returns the current value. Also see http://api.jquery.com/val/

*Please be aware that `input type=text` always returns a `String` when asked for its value.*

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is quiet different from JavaScript you cannot assi gn values with assignment operator you gave to do like this `$('#gg').Val(8);`

Comment: This answer has already been given. What is your answer adding here, except for a typographical error (capital `v` in `val`)?